# Fitting ng-bootstrap carousel on div inside ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

i've been trying to properly set the css properties to have a ng-bootstrap carousel image fit into a given space (div) inside a custom ng-bootstrap modal. Watch this forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyyp8-8bmbml) code.

As seen in the sample source, the image overlaps the given space (height) of the modal as well as the `col-8` where it is placed.

How do i make carousel follow the size of its parent `col-8`? so as to not overlap with modal size.

***UPDATE***

For those who can't see the issue, you can visit the actual app [here](https://angular-csyyp8-8bmbml.stackblitz.io)

After some trial and error, i've come to this point. Only `carousel-inner` and its children does not follow its parent div which is `ngb-carousel.carousel-modal`. See this image below

[image]

As shown in the image above, i can't make `carousel-inner` follow the size of its parent `ngb-carousel.carousel-modal` which already follow the modal height. it always overlaps and extends over the `carousel-modal` height. Do note that i set them to `max-height:100%` to make it responsive.

Comment: Remove the height styles in the modal-component.

Comment: Nope, i need carousel to follow the height of modal, specifically the `div.col-8` inside the modal.  not the other way around

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of your issue. The stackblitz seems to be containing the carousel to the modal correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: @EricS sorry must've updated the css, i reverted it back. if you still can't see it. please refer to updated info above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of understanding `height`, `max-height` and its relation to its parent tag. I've came up with the fix. see updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyyp8-8bmbml) here.

Basically, i made the image resize to fit in parent content giving the parent content as well as the img a fix height. Therefore, it will make the image auto resize to fit its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a fixed height within the container (that has a fixed height too).  Then position the carousel caption accordingly, like so:

```
img {
    height: 650px; /*adjust for your project*/
    width: auto !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
  img { width: 100% !important
   }    
} 

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 3%; /*adjust for your project*/
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 50%; /*adjust for your project*/
}
```

Play around with the values til it fits your needs.

Comment: tried this one, seems to make the image fixed, i need it to be responsive and adjust accordingly as you size up/down. so mostly i need the height/width in percent. However, can't seem to make it fit its parent div `carousel-inner`

Comment: You need media queries to fit in the img (and maybe the caption too) on smaller devices. (Updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to bring height 100% down the hierarchy of tags.

To set the modal-body height I set 100% - Modal Header Height (69px).

```css
.modal-body {
    height: Calc(100% - 69px);
}

ngbd-modal-content, ngb-carousel, .carousel-inner, .modal-body .row {
  height:100%;
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyyp8-heb7xf?file=styles.css

Comment: This does not main its responsive, as you size down o size up the modal, carousel image caption will be hidden.